# In SAS, drop data conditional on a trading week with any missing weekdays

Tags: sas, missing-data

In my case below, the figures under 'weekdays' 2-6 indicate Mondays to Fridays. In the third week the figure 2 which is Monday of the week is missing. I want to delete the rest data of this week to ensure any week will have complete trading days. Can you please give me some helps?  Thank you very much in advance!

```
Date     Weekdays   Volume
2000/01/03  2   1014411712
2000/01/04  3   1088000256
2000/01/05  4   1281538944
2000/01/06  5   1197224320
2000/01/07  6   1303269504
2000/01/10  2   1118983936
2000/01/11  3   1128259456
2000/01/12  4   1096179072
2000/01/13  5   1033687488
2000/01/14  6   1174890624
2000/01/18  3   1075011840
2000/01/19  4   1096254464
2000/01/20  5   1121080064
2000/01/21  6   1223604992
```

Comment: As a practical matter, I would be wary of deleting weeks like this if you're trying to analyze trends.  Holiday weeks have definite tendencies in the stock market, and you lose some information by removing the weeks.

Comment: @Joe thank you very much for reminding me this. I am trying to analysing the day of the week effect by using dummy variables. I think you are right. The missing dates won't matter a lot.

Comment: I'd analyze it both ways and see what you see.  Tuesdays in holiday monday weeks, or Wednesday before Thanksgiving, would be interesting to know whether they're like normal Tuesdays/Wednesdays or more like Mondays/Fridays.

Comment: @Joe Agreed, we often see the Tuesday bump after a Monday holiday.  Definitely worth checking both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select *
  from have
  group by week(date)
  having count(*)=5
  order by date
  ;
quit;
```

Assuming you don't have dups, or other such problems.

HTH,
--Q.